# Angular error : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular, ngfor

I'm doing a NodeJS/Angular program to retrieve data from SQL Server. However, when I try to get my data into a table, I get this error :

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Here's some parts of my code related to that error:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Issues.getIssue(function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(400).json(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.json(rows);
                }
            });
        });
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.issuesService
      .getIssue()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.issueslist = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

```
  <tr *ngFor="let issue of issueslist">
    <td>{{ issue.Id_OnCall_Issue }}</td>
    <td>{{ issue.OnCall_Issue }}</td>
</tr>
```

Here's my full 'data' results from the console.log:

```
{recordsets: Array(1), recordset: Array(16), output: {…}, rowsAffected: Array(1)}
output: {}
recordset: Array(16)
0: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 1, OnCall_Issue: "Pb C"}
1: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 2, OnCall_Issue: "Pb  E"}
2: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 3, OnCall_Issue: "Pb S"}
3: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 4, OnCall_Issue: "Pb KISS"}
4: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 5, OnCall_Issue: "Pb BDD mongoDB"}
5: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 6, OnCall_Issue: "Pb BDD SQL Server"}
6: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 7, OnCall_Issue: "Pb R"}
7: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 8, OnCall_Issue: "Pb TR"}
8: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 9, OnCall_Issue: "Pb AWS"}
9: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 10, OnCall_Issue: "Pb KAFKA"}
10: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 11, OnCall_Issue: "Pb Data Center"}
11: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 12, OnCall_Issue: "Pb Réseau AWS"}
12: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 13, OnCall_Issue: "Pb Export"}
13: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 14, OnCall_Issue: "Pb API"}
14: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 15, OnCall_Issue: "Pb Storage"}
15: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 16, OnCall_Issue: "Pb K8S"}
length: 16
__proto__: Array(0)
recordsets: [Array(16)]
rowsAffected: [16]
__proto__: Object
```

How can I fix this please?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Change the line `this.issueslist = data;` to `this.issueslist = data.recordsets;`

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error :  Property 'recordsets' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: That is a typescript error, use `this.issueslist = (data as any).recordsets`

Comment: Thank you so much @OwenKelvin, this.issueslist = (data as any).recordset solved it! I have my results now. Have a great day :D